# How to compare two polyline of google map?

Tags: google-maps, routes, polyline, direction

I am working on an app that tracks user location and makes a route on google map.
I am providing a google map polyline to travel on that. currently, I want to know that user is travelling on provided polyline(route) or not.
So I need to compare provided polyline(route) and user traveling polyline(route).

Please help me to find a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think, u need to check whether the user coordinate is in gmspolyline or not.
For that you can use 
**GMSGeometryContainsLocation (CLLocationCoordinate2D point, GMSPath *path, BOOL geodesic)**

U just pass GMSpath and Coordinate of user, it return BOOL yes, if user coordinate is in GMSpath